# mod_wsgi and EC2 how to compile against httpd provided

Tags: python, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install install mod_wsgi on a EC2 instance. I'm using the amazon 64bit linux ami , and the problem is how do I install it when apxs doesn't exist in this image. Instead it uses httpd for the apache configuration. The problem is the compiled version of mod_wsgi is python 2.6.6 where the core python 2.6.7

Any help on how to do I add `--with-apxs=`? since there isn't a file to use to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter that there is a patch level revision difference so long as the Python installation provides a shared library and mod_wsgi is using the Python shared library. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Version_Mismatch

There would only be an issue if the major/minor version were different such as one being for Python 2.6 and the other for Python 2.7.

Comment: I ended up find out what it was. It was a permission problem. Thanks any how